# Select random values, where interval is between two columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have two columns in my table. AmountMin and AmountMax. I need to SELECT random value between this two columns. May anyone help me?

```
SELECT
T.[Type]
, T.[Operation Name]
, -- Rand expression AS RandomAmount
```

FROM DBO.Transactions T

```
Min     Max   
100000  250000
500000  4000000
100000  200000
200000  500000
4000000 6000000
300 350
5000000 1500000
150000  350000
1000000 150000
50000   70000
10000   15000
600 1000
2000000 4000000
```

And I need one column with random values where interval is between this two columns

Comment: can you post the output ?

Comment: This is unclear. Do you want to return a value from a randomly selected existing row, or generate a random value?

Comment: want to select random value between two rows (.AmountMin and .AmountMax) as one row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try..

```
SELECT RAND()*(b-a)+a; --Where a is the smallest number and
 b is the largest number
```

Your Query..

```
SELECT
T.[Type]
, T.[Operation Name]
,(RAND()*(b-a)+a) as random1
FROM DBO.Transactions T
```

[Here is The Full reference](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/rand.php)